# query en java, clave primaria Long,Por qué error de "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;"?

Tags: java, sql, entity-framework, cast

Intento que mi servidor de Back End en STS Java me devuelva un Integer o Long que será mayor que uno si me encuentra un usuario que exista con ese email (falta verificar la password, pero no se hacer una query que me verifique que el campo password corresponda con el que envío , poco a poco, mejor hago la pregunta en otro hilo sobre eso). Y sera -1 o -2 o -algo para enviarme mensajes de errores.

```
String sql = "select U.id from sanihelp.usuario U where "
                    + "U.email like ?";
            try {
                Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter(1,email);
                for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
                        Object[] objeto = (Object[]) o;
                        if (objeto !=null) {
                            System.out.println("Ese email existe"+((BigInteger) objeto [0]).longValue());
                            return ((BigInteger) objeto[0]).longValue();
                        }
                    }               
                } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("excepcion lanzada en UsuarioDAO autenticar" + e);
                }
```

cuando me controlador ejecuta Servicio Implementado y este a su vez ejecuta el DAO, todo va bien hasta la línea inferior a FOR que me da el error indicado en titulo. Supongo que mi "o" debe tener un valor de BigInteger y al hacer el cast me da error. No veo cual es la razón. Supongo que objeto tendrá solo un campo "objeto[0]" que será el ID devuelto.
Gracias

nota:
En otro DAO hago,

```
for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
                Object[] objeto = (Object[]) o;
                HiloDTO hilo = new HiloDTO();

                hilo.setIdRespuesta(((BigInteger) objeto[0]).longValue());
                hilo.setPuntuacion((Integer)objeto[2]);
```

pero como solo estoy recuperando un valor de ID tipo BigInteger de la BBDD no creo deba crear otro modelo con solo un campo. Supongo que podré devolver el valor sin más, ¿no?

Comment: Estas intentando guardar un array de objetos como un biginteger

Comment: Gracias Pablo nuevamente por tu ayuda. Si, ya se que devuelvo un array, pero pensé que podia coger el valor del campo único [0], donde guarda el ID y devolverlo sin necesidad de crear más variables (modelos). Veo que no es así.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás intentando crear un array de objetos cuando tienes un BigInteger. Creo que con esto te bastaría:

```
String sql = "select U.id from sanihelp.usuario U where U.email like ?";
try {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter(1,email);
    List<BigInteger[]> resultado = query.getResultList();
    if (!resultado.isEmpty()) {
        BigInteger[] o = resultado.get(0); // Es una lista de arrays
        return o[0].longValue();
    }
    return null;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("excepcion lanzada en UsuarioDAO autenticar" + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta solución. No me termina de llenar, pero mientras nadie me diga otra, será la que aplique. Uso un objetoDTO simplemente como intermediario. Solo uso el campo id de los que tiene. Es por no crear otro modelo (¿que es mejor o se hace más, yo soy nuevo?)
Mi solución es:

```
public Long autenticar(String email) {
            String sql = "select U.id from sanihelp.usuario U where "
                    + "U.email like ?";
            try {
                Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter(1,email);
                for (Object o : query.getResultList()) {
                    BigInteger objeto = (BigInteger) o;

                        LoginDTO auxiliar= new LoginDTO();
                        auxiliar.setId(((BigInteger) objeto).longValue());
                            return auxiliar.getId();

                    }               
                } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("excepcion lanzada en UsuarioDAO autenticar" + e);
                }
            System.out.println("Ese email NO existe");
            return (long) -1;   
        }
```

De esta manera devuelvo el valor del id del usuario con ese email.

Comment: No voy a usar objetoDTO, me creare un modelo que tenga solamente un campo. No me parece bien usar un objetoDTO que además tiene más campos solo para eso. Gracias